# Why haproxy can not set custom header for ingress-nginx

Tags: nginx, haproxy

I have config haproxy.cfg like bellow

```
...
frontend app
        bind *:443
        mode tcp
        option  tcplog
        option forwardfor
        http-request set-header X-AONE-IP 10.0.0.1
        http-request set-header myheader 123

        use_backend be

backend be
        mode tcp
        http-request set-header X-AONE-IP 10.0.0.1
        http-request set-header myheader 123
        option forwardfor

        balance roundrobin
        server backend 127.0.0.1:9000 check
...
```

but on backend, I can not receive header X-AONE-IP neither myheader, when I using postman and set those header on postman to make request to haproxy or 127.0.0.1:9000, my backend app can receive that header

Answer (score 2):

You use `mode tcp`, so all `http` commands don't work. Switch mode to `http`.